# Обработать клик только внутри родителя, где он был сделан

Tags: jquery

По клику на кнопку, получаем текст из `.dodo` и копируем в `.modal`

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var text = $('.dodo').text();
    $(".modal").append(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="dodo">Котелок!</div>
  <button>УрраКнопка</button>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="dodo">ДОДО</div>
  <button>ДодоКнопка</button>
</div>

<div class="modal"></div>
```

Задача: по клику, вставлять в `.modal` текст ТОЛЬКО из блока `.dodo`, в котором он вместе с нажимаемой кнопкой, находятся внутри своего `div'a` `.bar`. Т.е. провести работу скрипта только внутри родителя, в котором и кнопка и блок с текстом находятся.

Сейчас по клику, в блок `.modal` вставляется текст из обоих источников. Полагаю, нужно использовать `this`, но не могу понять, как именно..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var text = $(this).closest(".bar").find(".dodo").text();
```

или

```
var text = $(this).siblings(".dodo").text();
```

Comment: при клике на разные кнопки вставляет текст из обоих dodo...там  contenteditable   https://jsfiddle.net/nnykrrpL/6/

Comment: Благодарю, использую ваш первый вариант!

Answer (score 1):

Как то так, главное кнопку глубже не прячь.

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
   var text = $(this).parent().find('.dodo').text();
    $(".modal").append(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="dodo">Котелок!</div>
  <button>УрраКнопка</button>
</div>

<div class="bar">
  <div class="dodo">ДОДО</div>
  <button>ДодоКнопка</button>
</div>

<div class="modal"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант!